# Django-Tastypie: How Do You Access (Http)request object in the Bundle?

Tags: django, api, resources, tastypie

I need to access the HttpRequest object in my Resource's dehydrate 
method.

In the docs, it shows that bundle.request is a valid attribute (it's 
in the resources.html page). When I try to add it to my code, I get an 
error claiming that Bundle' object has no attribute 'request'. 
What gives?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just had the same problem, but found the correct answer over here:
http://groups.google.com/group/django-tastypie/tree/browse_frm/thread/801f44af3f2dbe7b/a36f303380eacf96

it seems django-tasty-pie version 0.9.9 didn't have this attribute but version 0.9.10 does!

so if you use buildout, look in to buildout.cfg
under versions:
search for `django-tastypie = 0.9.9`

remove this one and see what your install picks or replace it with:

```
django-tastypie = 0.9.10
```

I still have this problem, so opened a new link, see:

[django-tastypie: Cannot access bundle.request in dehydrate(self,bundle)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8263331)

in the question above I found out, that using 0.9.10 is not enough, version 1.0.0 beta should do the tric..

Answer (score 3):

Bundle object has request attribute.

```
class Bundle(object):
    """
    A small container for instances and converted data for the
    ``dehydrate/hydrate`` cycle.

    Necessary because the ``dehydrate/hydrate`` cycle needs to access data at
    different points.
    """
    def __init__(self, obj=None, data=None, request=None):
        self.obj = obj
        self.data = data or {}
        self.request = request or HttpRequest()
```

Anyway, you can ovveride the Resource method higher than `dehydrate` in the call stack.

Could you show the code?