# django-tastypie: Cannot access bundle.request in dehydrate(self,bundle)

Tags: django, tastypie

I found someone with the same problem, but the solation for him doesn't work with me:
see
[Django-Tastypie: How Do You Access (Http)request object in the Bundle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7389632)

I Am trying to apply the workaround suggested in:
[Django tastypie: Resource show different in detailed request as in list request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8242969/)

resulting in this code in my resources file (api.py):

```
class LocationResource(ModelResource):
    locationtype = fields.ForeignKey(LocationTypeResource, 'locationtype', full=False)

    class Meta:
        queryset = Location.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'location'
        excludes = ['public_anonymous', 'public_authorized','x','y','z']
        authentication = BasicAuthentication()
        authorization = DjangoAuthorization()

    def dehydrate(self, bundle):
        if bundle.request:
            if bundle.request.path: == "/api/v1/location/":
                del bundle.data['description']
            else:

                logger.debug("request availabe")
        else:
            logger.debug("request not availabe")
        return bundle
```

I get the error:

```
{
error_message: "'Bundle' object has no attribute 'request'",
traceback: "Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/home/michel/django/sites/regelwater/eggs/django_tastypie-0.9.10-py2.6.egg/tastypie/resources.py", line 178, in wrapper
    response = callback(request, *args, **kwargs)

  File "/home/michel/django/sites/regelwater/eggs/django_tastypie-0.9.10-py2.6.egg/tastypie/resources.py", line 379, in dispatch_list
    return self.dispatch('list', request, **kwargs)

  File "/home/michel/django/sites/regelwater/eggs/django_tastypie-0.9.10-py2.6.egg/tastypie/resources.py", line 409, in dispatch
    response = method(request, **kwargs)

  File "/home/michel/django/sites/regelwater/eggs/django_tastypie-0.9.10-py2.6.egg/tastypie/resources.py", line 987, in get_list
    to_be_serialized['objects'] = [self.full_dehydrate(obj=obj) for obj in to_be_serialized['objects']]

  File "/home/michel/django/sites/regelwater/eggs/django_tastypie-0.9.10-py2.6.egg/tastypie/resources.py", line 638, in full_dehydrate
    bundle = self.dehydrate(bundle)

  File "/home/michel/django/sites/regelwater/reservoir/api.py", line 71, in dehydrate
    if bundle.request:

AttributeError: 'Bundle' object has no attribute 'request'
"
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're probably running Tastypie 9.10 if you installed from pypi. The Bundle object in the pypi version [does indeed not have a request object](https://github.com/toastdriven/django-tastypie/blob/a9b6b23d6c3cc62ed3379089fa2d57d2d5b341ef/tastypie/bundle.py#L10).

If you upgrade to the git version of django-tastypie master and use that instead the problem should be resolved.

```
pip uninstall django-tastypie 
pip install -e git+https://github.com/toastdriven/django-tastypie.git#egg=django-tastypie
```

Comment: Thanx for the answer, but: Because of several seperate webapplications on 1 server, I prefer not or at least install as less as possible on the server itselve. Therefor I use buildout. Using buildout, I get to pypi.

Comment: by the way, it's goot to know, because in other answers they said I needed 9.10 in stead of 9.10, so I was very pleased to see version 9.10 apeared on pypi, and very dissapointed after that. At least now I Know why. (that's why I upvoted)

Comment: 9.10 means 0.9.10... As of today the latest tastypie is 0.10.0.